# simple for loop needing explained

Tags: python

I know this is going to sound silly but I cannot for the life of me figure out the logic behind how this for loop returns 13,11,9,7.

```
    for i in range(13,5,-1):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            print i
```

I know the first value is the number it starts with, the second is where it stops, and the third being the steps it takes. The "if i % 2 !=0:" is what is throwing me off. Can anybody explain what is happening for me?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a question from not very long ago?  I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: ummm. I hope not. I searched and didn't see anything explaining what I was looking for. Sorry if I made a mistake.

Comment: I found it.  The original question was deleted about two hours ago, which is why it wasn't showing up, and probably why you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first bit is the `range(13,5,-1)` which just counts backwards from `13` to `6`.  The next bit is `i%2 != 0`.  `i%2 == 0` is equivalent to saying `if even`, or "if this number can be divided by 2 with no remainder", so your statment is saying "`if odd`" (which is obviously the same as "`if not even`").

Basically, the loop is printing odd numbers starting at 13 and decreasing down to 6 (but 6 is even, so it doesn't get printed)

Comment: Holy crap that is awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

% is the modulo operator. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html):

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the
>   first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first
>   converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the
>   ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point
>   numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.)
>   The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its
>   second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly
>   smaller than the absolute value of the second operand.

Answer (score 2):

```
if i % 2 !=0
```

That line means "if the remainder after dividing i by 2 is not equal to 0," so it's checking to see if i is odd.  The for loop is counting down by 1, but the if statement skips printing the even numbers.